# Cassandra and Python Driver - Getting Duplicate Rows

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to use the Cassandra and Python driver to get data out of a Cassandra database.

This is my `cql` command to generate a table, and keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE regression WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};

USE regression;

CREATE TABLE results (
uuid text,
jobname text,
date text,
block text,
results text,
metrics text,
PRIMARY KEY ((uuid), jobname, date, block));
```

When I open `cql`, and type in `select block from results`, I get the following:

```
 block
------------------------
            simple_buff
 simple_buff_pre_commit
```

However, when I do the same thing in python:

```
from cassandra.policies import RetryPolicy
cluster = Cluster(
  contact_points=['127.0.0.1'],
   default_retry_policy = RetryPolicy()
  )
session = cluster.connect('regression')
results = session.execute("select block from results")
for result in results:
    print results
    print "END"
```

It gives me:

```
[Row(block=u'simple_buff'), Row(block=u'simple_buff_pre_commit')]
END
[Row(block=u'simple_buff'), Row(block=u'simple_buff_pre_commit')]
END
```

Why does it returns a Row with two item compared to cql client which only returns me two rows with one item? If I do `select * from results` in python, it will give me two copies of the same row twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
print results
```

It should be result without 's'

```
print result
```

Comment: Thats why... Sometimes I keep forgetting to check my spelling.